# How to reshape a nonlinear inquality into a linear matrix inequality?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

We have these two nonlinear inequalities (I):
$$x^2+y^2>0$$
$$3x^2+3y^2-4y^6>0$$
We want to represent this problem as a Linear Matrix Inequality Problem, i.e, we want to derive a positive definite matrix A such that $A>0$ implies (I)

1- How to solve this particular problem?
2- What is the general method of solving these problems?

*note: I've tried Schur lemma with no avail

Comment: Is it Schor or Schur?

Comment: @dineshdileep Schur. Any idea?

Comment: This is a nonconvex set so it can never be written as a LMI

Comment: @JohanLöfberg Good point there professor Lofberg. How did you find out that the problem is not convex? I mean was there a simple inspection or did you plot the region?

Comment: Trivially $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$ are feasible, but the point in-between $(0,0)$ is not Hence not convex